# flask TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, sys

hey guys i am new to flask and i am trying to import data from sqlite to my index.hmtl but i kept facing this error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` even though my data has no none values. the code for the route.py and index.html is provided.

route.py

```
def get_entries():
    try:
        entries = Entry.query.all()
        return 
    except Exception as error:
        db.session.rollback()
        flash(error,"danger") 
        return 0
```

index.html

```
<tbody>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{ entry.age}}</td>
        <td>{{ entry.sex }}</td>
        <td>{{ entry.cp}}</td>
        <td>{{ entry.thalach }}</td>
        <td>{{ entry.prediction  }}</td>
        <td>{{ entry.predicted_on}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning your entries from the `get_entries` function! Try this:

```
def get_entries():
    try:
        entries = Entry.query.all()
        return entries
    except Exception as error:
        db.session.rollback()
        flash(error,"danger") 
        return 0
```